# How to write an algorithm to check if the sum of any two numbers in an array/list matches a given number?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

How can I write an algorithm to check if the sum of any two numbers in an array/list matches a given number
with a complexity of `nlogn`?

Comment: What do you expect as output? The numbers? Their index? What if more than one results is possible?

Comment: Do you want a true/false answer "yes, there is a couple" or do you want all pairs? Or all possible combinations that gives the demanded sum?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but here's an idea:

1. Sort array
2. For every element *e* in the array, binary search for the complement *(sum - e)*

Both these operations are `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Also, after sorting, discard all the numbers which are bigger than sum. I assume that you have all positive integers.

Comment: yeah that's what i though and then i got all busy trying to compute the complexity it never occured to me that both the operations are o(nlogn)

Comment: You don't have to search for every elements actually. Since you've sorted the array, stop searching at `sum/2` (doesn't impact the big O, but still :p)

Answer (score 28):

This can be done in `O(n)` using a hash table. Initialize the table with all numbers in the array, with number as the key, and frequency as the value. Walk through each number in the array, and see if `(sum - number)` exists in the table. If it does, you have a match. After you've iterated through all numbers in the array, you should have a list of all pairs that sum up to the desired number.

```
array = initial array
table = hash(array)
S = sum

for each n in array
    if table[S-n] exists
        print "found numbers" n, S-n
```

The case where n and table[S-n] refer to the same number twice can be dealt with an extra check, but the complexity remains `O(n)`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it is O(n) whilst the accepted answer is O(n logn)

Comment: It should not be accepted as the best answer unless the author can explain how his proposed solution would handle non-distinct sets of inputs. (What if some of the numbers in the initially randomized suite are duplicates of one another)?

Comment: The value in the hash table will represent the number of times a number appears in the list. That will allow handling of duplicates.

Answer (score 21):

Use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Insert every number into your hash table, along with its index. Then, let `S` be your desired sum. For every number `array[i]` in your initial array, see if `S - array[i]` exists in your hash table with an index different than `i`.

Average case is `O(n)`, worst case is `O(n^2)`, so use the binary search solution if you're afraid of the worst case.

Comment: I don't get the worst case. Using a hash table should get you `O(1)` on insertion and look-up (with some care) or do you account for potential hash conflicts ? Anyway this seems even better than using binary search.

Comment: Yes, there could be hash conflicts. For example, consider the array `{1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1, ...}` that contains `n` ones. We want to make the sum 20. You would add all the ones in the same position in the hash table. Then, for each 1 you would check if 19 is in the array. Let's assume that the value 19 maps to the same location in your hash table that the value 1 does. This means that for each of the `n` ones you will do `n` checks in your hash table, giving you quadratic time complexity. Similar examples can be found for the case where there is a solution (use 3 values - one dominant)

Comment: you could map the frequency as the value for each associated number. so if you have 8 1s, the hash will map `1 => 8`. When a sum of 2 is desired, for example, you put an additional check - if the current number equals the target number `(S - array[i])`, then it's frequency must be at least 2.

Answer (score 10):

Let us say that we want to find two numbers in the array A that when added together equal N.

1. Sort the array.
2. Find the largest number in the array that is less than N/2.  Set the index of that number as *lower*.
3. Initialize *upper* to be *lower* + 1.
4. Set *sum* = A[*lower*] + A[*upper*].
5. If *sum* == N, done.
6. If *sum* < N, increment *upper*.
7. If *sum* > N, decrement *lower*.
8. If either *lower* or *upper* is outside the array, done without any matches.
9. Go back to 4.

The sort can be done in O(n log n).  The search is done in linear time.

Answer (score 4):

This is in Java : This even removes the possible duplicates.. Runtime - `O(n^2)`

```
private static int[] intArray = {15,5,10,20,25,30};
private static int sum = 35;

private static void algorithm()
{
    Map<Integer, Integer> intMap = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++) 
    {
        intMap.put(i, intArray[i]);
        if(intMap.containsValue(sum - intArray[i]))
            System.out.println("Found numbers : "+intArray[i] +" and "+(sum - intArray[i]));

    }
    System.out.println(intMap);
}
```

Comment: This solution is suboptimal, since `containsValue` runs in linear time, hence the total running time is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_in(numbers, sum_):
    """whether any two numbers from `numbers` form `sum_`."""
    a = set(numbers) # O(n)
    return any((sum_ - n) in a for n in a) # O(n)
```

Example:

```
>>> sum_in([200, -10, -100], 100)
True
```

Comment: Note: this solution allows repetition i.e., it doesn't distinguish `[1]` and `[1, 1]` cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try in C.  This isn't marked homework.

```c
// Assumes a sorted integer array with no duplicates
void printMatching(int array[], int size, int sum)
{
   int i = 0, k = size - 1;
   int curSum;
   while(i < k)
   {
      curSum = array[i] + array[k];
      if(curSum == sum)
      {
         printf("Found match at indices %d, %d\n", i, k);
         i++;k--;
      }
      else if(curSum < sum)
      {
         i++;
      }
      else
      {
         k--;
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some test output using `int a[] = { 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15, 17 };`

```
Searching for 12..
Found match at indices 0, 5
Found match at indices 1, 3
Searching for 22...
Found match at indices 1, 8
Found match at indices 3, 7
Found match at indices 5, 6
Searching for 4..
Searching for 50..
```

The search is linear, so O(n).  The sort that takes place behind the scenes is going to be O(n*logn) if you use one of the good sorts.

Because of the math behind Big-O, the smaller term in additive terms will effectively drop out of your calculation, and you end up with O(n logn).

Answer (score 1):

This one is O(n)

```csharp
public static bool doesTargetExistsInList(int Target, int[] inputArray)
{
    if (inputArray != null && inputArray.Length > 0 )
    {
        Hashtable inputHashTable = new Hashtable();

        // This hash table will have all the items in the input array and how many times they appeard
        Hashtable duplicateItems = new Hashtable();

        foreach (int i in inputArray)
        {
            if (!inputHashTable.ContainsKey(i))
            {
                inputHashTable.Add(i, Target - i);
                duplicateItems.Add(i, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                duplicateItems[i] = (int)duplicateItems[i] + 1;    
            }

        }

        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in inputHashTable)
        {
            if ((int)de.Key == (int)de.Value)
            {
                if ((int)duplicateItems[de.Key] > 1)
                return true;
            }
            else if (inputHashTable.ContainsKey(de.Value))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This uses 2 passes. But it could be done in just 1 pass, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm that runs in O(n) if array is already sorted or O(n log n) if it isn't already sorted. Takes cues from lot of other answers here. Code is in Java, but here is a pseudo code as well derived from lot of existing answers, but optimized for duplicates generally

1. Lucky guess if first and last elements are equal to target
2. Create a Map with current value and its occurrences
3. Create a visited Set which contains items we already saw, this optimizes for duplicates such that say with an input of (1,1,1,1,1,1,2) and target 4, we only ever compute for 0 and last element and not all the 1's in the array.
4. Use these variables to compute existence of target in the array;
   set the currentValue to array[ith];
   set newTarget to target - currentValue;
   set expectedCount to 2 if currentValue equals newTarget or 1 otherwise

   AND return true only if
   a. we never saw this integer before AND
   b. we have some value for the newTarget in the map we created
   c. and the count for the newTarget is equal or greater than the expectedCount

OTHERWISE
   repeat step 4 till we reach end of array and return false OTHERWISE;

Like I mentioned the best possible use for a visited store is when we have duplicates, it would never help if none of elements are duplicates.

Java Code at https://gist.github.com/eded5dbcee737390acb4

Answer (score 0):

Depends If you want only one sum O(N) or O(N log N) or all sums O(N^2) or O(N^2 log N). In the latter case better uses an FFT>

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Sort the array in O(n logn)

Step 2 : Find two indices

> 0<=i<j<=n in a[0..n] such that a[i]+a[j]==k, where k is given key.

```
int i=0,j=n;
while(i<j) {
   int sum = a[i]+a[j];
   if(sum == k)
        print(i,j)
   else if (sum < k)
        i++;
   else if (sum > k)
        j--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void sumOfTwoQualToTargetSum()
    {
        List<int> list= new List<int>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(7);
        list.Add(9);

        int targetsum = 12;

        int[] arr = list.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((i != j) && ((arr[i] + arr[j]) == targetsum))
                {
                    Console.Write("i =" + i);
                    Console.WriteLine("j =" + j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Solved the question in Swift 4.0
2. Solved in 3 different ways (with 2 different type of return -> Boolean and Indexes)

A) TimeComplexity => 0(n Log n) SpaceComplexity => 0(n).

B) TimeComplexity => 0(n^2) SpaceComplexity => 0(1).

C) TimeComplexity => 0(n) SpaceComplexity => 0(n)

3. Choose Solution A, B or C depending on TradeOff.

   ```
   //***********************Solution A*********************//
   //This solution returns TRUE if any such two pairs exist in the array
   func binarySearch(list: [Int], key: Int, start: Int, end: Int) -> Int? { //Helper Function

               if end < start {
                   return -1
               } else {
                   let midIndex = (start + end) / 2

                   if list[midIndex] > key {
                       return binarySearch(list: list, key: key, start: start, end:  midIndex - 1)
                   } else if list[midIndex] < key {
                       return binarySearch(list: list, key: key, start: midIndex + 1, end: end)
                   } else {
                       return midIndex
                   }
               }
           }

           func twoPairSum(sum : Int, inputArray: [Int]) -> Bool {

               //Do this only if array isn't Sorted!
               let sortedArray = inputArray.sorted()

               for (currentIndex, value)  in sortedArray.enumerated() {
                   if let indexReturned =  binarySearch(list: sortedArray, key: sum - value, start: 0, end: sortedArray.count-1) {
                       if indexReturned != -1 && (indexReturned != currentIndex) {
                           return true
                       }
                   }
               }
               return false
           }

    //***********************Solution B*********************//
    //This solution returns the indexes of the two pair elements if any such two pairs exists in the array
    func twoPairSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {

               for currentIndex in 0..<nums.count {
                   for nextIndex in currentIndex+1..<nums.count {
                       if calculateSum(firstElement: nums[currentIndex], secondElement: nums[nextIndex], target: target) {
                           return [currentIndex, nextIndex]
                       }
                   }
               }

               return []
           }

           func calculateSum (firstElement: Int, secondElement: Int, target: Int) -> Bool {//Helper Function
               return (firstElement + secondElement) == target
           }

       //*******************Solution C*********************//
      //This solution returns the indexes of the two pair elements if any such two pairs exists in the array
      func twoPairSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {

               var dict = [Int: Int]()

               for (index, value) in nums.enumerated() {
                   dict[value] = index
               }

               for (index, value) in nums.enumerated() {
                   let otherIndex = dict[(target - value)]
                   if otherIndex != nil && otherIndex != index {
                       return [index, otherIndex!]
                   }
               }

               return []
           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This question is missing some more details into it. Like what is the return value, the limitation on the input.
I have seen some questions related to that, which can be this question with extra requirement, `to return the actual elements that result in the input`

Here is my version of the solution, it should be `O(n)`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class IntegerSum {

    private static final int[] NUMBERS = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] result = IntegerSum.isSumExist(7);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    /**
     * n = x + y
     * 7 = 1 + 6
     * 7 - 1 =  6
     * 7 - 6 = 1
     * The subtraction of one element in the array should result into the value of the other element if it exist;
     */
    public static int[] isSumExist(int n) {
        // validate the input, based on the question
        // This to return the values that actually result in the sum. which is even more tricky
        int[] output = new int[2];
        Map resultsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        // O(n)
        for (int number : NUMBERS) {
            if ( number > n )
                throw new IllegalStateException("The number is not in the array.");
            if ( resultsMap.containsKey(number) ) {
                output[0] = number;
                output[1] = (Integer) resultsMap.get(number);
                return output;
            }
            resultsMap.put(n - number, number);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("The number is not in the array.");
    }
}
```