# A recursive algorithm to find two integers in an array that sums to a given integer

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I need an algorithm to determine if an array contains two elements that sum to a given integer.

The array is sorted.

The algorithm should be **recursive** and runs in O(n).

The recursive step should be based on the sum, meaning the method passes the sum and return true or false depending on the end result (if two elements are found - return true, else - return false)

Only linear data structures can be used.

Any ideas are appreciated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write an algorithm to check if the sum of any two numbers in an array/list matches a given number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666654/how-to-write-an-algorithm-to-check-if-the-sum-of-any-two-numbers-in-an-array-lis)

Comment: @akf: I came up with a non-recursive method, but I don't understand how to convert it to a recursive method.  The non-recursive method is as follows:

1. create two variables called sum, start and end with start=1st element of the array and end=last element of the array...
2. sum=Array[start]+Array[end]...
3. if (sum>k) where k is the given integer, then decrement end...
4. else if (sum<k), then increment start...
5. if start==end then stop...
6. if sum==k then stop...
7. go back to step 2...

Comment: Now you should convert steps 3 and 4 to recursive calls of your function and returning value will be the same thar recursive call returned.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert any iterative algorithm into a recursive one by using (for instance) [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion).  I'd be more expansive, if it weren't homework.  I think you'll understand it from the other post.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd use a Map, but since one of the requirements is to use a linear data structure, I think that's excluded, so I'd go about using a boolean array.

```
public boolean hasSum( int[] numbers, int target )
{
    boolean[] hits = new boolean[ target + 1 ];
    return hasSumRecursive( 0, numbers, target, hits );
}

public boolean hasSumRecursive( int index, int[] numbers, int target, boolean[] hits )
{
    ...
}
```

Hopefully this is a good enough hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think hash is ok, for example, 1,3,7,9,12,14,33...

if we want sum=21, we hash the numbers into a hash table,  So, O(n).

we iterator them, when we get 7, we let 21-7=14, so we hash 14, we can find it. so 7+14=21,

we got it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution witch takes into account duplicate entries. It is written in javascript and assumes array is sorted.  The solution runs in O(n) time and does not use any extra memory aside from variable.

```
var count_pairs = function(_arr,x) {
  if(!x) x = 0;
  var pairs = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var k = _arr.length-1;
  if((k+1)<2) return pairs;
  var halfX = x/2; 
  while(i<k) {
    var curK = _arr[k];
    var curI = _arr[i];
    var pairsThisLoop = 0;
    if(curK+curI==x) {
      // if midpoint and equal find combinations
      if(curK==curI) {
        var comb = 1;
        while(--k>=i) pairs+=(comb++);
        break;
      }
      // count pair and k duplicates
      pairsThisLoop++;
      while(_arr[--k]==curK) pairsThisLoop++;
      // add k side pairs to running total for every i side pair found
      pairs+=pairsThisLoop;
      while(_arr[++i]==curI) pairs+=pairsThisLoop;
    } else {
      // if we are at a mid point
      if(curK==curI) break;
      var distK = Math.abs(halfX-curK);
      var distI = Math.abs(halfX-curI);
      if(distI > distK) while(_arr[++i]==curI);
      else while(_arr[--k]==curK);
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}
```

I solved this during an interview for a large corporation.  They took it but not me.
So here it is for everyone.

Start at both side of the array and slowly work your way inwards making sure to count duplicates if they exist.

It only counts pairs but can be reworked to

- use recursion
- find the pairs
- find pairs < x
- find pairs > x

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy. It is important for **array** to be **sorted**.

Correct algorithm with **O(n)** time complexity and **no additional space** is:

```
public static boolean isContainsSum(int[] arr, int sum) {
    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; ) {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum)
            return true;
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] < sum)
            i++;
        else
            j--;
    }

    return false;
}
```

To make it recursive, you need just replace `i` and `j` iterations with recursive call:

```
public static boolean isContainsSumRecursive(int[] arr, int sum) {
    return isContainsSumRecursive(arr, sum, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

private static boolean isContainsSumRecursive(int[] arr, int sum, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j)
        return false;
    if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum)
        return true;
    if (arr[i] + arr[j] < sum)
        return isContainsSumRecursive(arr, sum, i + 1, j);
    return isContainsSumRecursive(arr, sum, i, j - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: I iterate until the first number is greater than the expected sum, then until to second one or the sum of two is greater than the expected sum. If I do not want a correct answer, I return {-1,-1} (assuming all numbers are positive integers)

```
{

private static int[] sumOfTwo(int[] input, int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
        int first = input[i];
        for (int j = 1; j < input.length; j++) {
            int second = input[j];
            int sum = first + second;
            if (sum == k) {
                int[] result = {first, second};
                return result;
            }
            if (second > k || sum > k) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (first > k) {
            break;
        }
    }
    int[] begin = {-1, -1};
    return begin;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursion method to perform the groupSum

```
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) 
{
    if (start >= nums.length) {
    return (target == 0);
}
return groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]) || groupSum(start + 
1,nums,target) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using recursion

```
pair<int,int> twoSum(int arr[], int s, int e, int target, pair<int, int>p){
//base case
if(arr[s] + arr[e] == target){
    // pair<int,int>p;
    p.first = arr[s];
    p.second = arr[e];
    return p;
}
while(s < e-1){
    if(arr[s] + arr[e] < target){
        s++;
        return twoSum(arr, s, e, target, p);
    }
    if(arr[s] + arr[e] > target){
        e--;
        return twoSum(arr, s, e, target, p);
    }
    
}
//if there is no pair possible
cout<<"pair is not possible" <<endl;
return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ExistsSum(A, i, j, Target):
    if i >= j:
        return False # Failure, all candidate pairs exhausted
    
    if A[i] + A[j] < Target:
        return ExistsSum(A, i+1, j, Target) # Try a larger sum
    
    if A[i] + A[j] > Target:
        return ExistsSum(A, i, j-1, Target) # Try a smaller sum
    
    return True # Success
```

Run with

```
ExistsSum(A, 0, len(A)-1, Target)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool solve(vector<int> &sorted_array, int l, int r, int target) {
    if(l>=r) {
        return false;
    }
    if(sorted_array[l] + sorted_array[r] == target) {
        return true;
    }

    if(sorted_array[l] + sorted_array[r] > target) {
        return solve(sorted_array, l, r-1, target);
    }

    if(sorted_array[l] + sorted_array[r] < target) {
        return solve(sorted_array, l+1, r, target);
    }

}

int main() {
    vector<int> a = ...
    solve(a, 0, a.size() - 1, target)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, first sort the array as then call the recursive function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15};
    Arrays.sort(input);

    System.out.println(twoSumWithRecursion(input, 99, 0, input.length-1));
}

private static String twoSumWithRecursion(int[] input, int target, int i, int j) {
    if (i == input.length-1 || j == 0) {
        return "Target not found";
    }
    if (input[i] + input[j] == target) {
        return String.format("Two numbers: %s %s", input[i], input[j]);
    }
    if (input[i] + input[j] < target) {
        return twoSumWithRecursion(input, target, i+1, j);
    }
    return twoSumWithRecursion(input, target, i, j-1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort the array. Search for the complement of each number (sum-number). Complexity O(nlogn).

Comment: Next time read the question. The array is sorted.